# UILabels disappear after I run Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I uses a TableView Controller to hold UILable in my habit tracker app. However, after I run Xcode, all the UILable disappear.

[image]
[image]

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwiftNewIdeaCreation: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    @IBAction func createButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: you are creating a prototype cells for a table view -- you will have to bind up that table view with a data model... google it up, and study it (e.g.: https://peterwitham.com/swift-archives/intermediate/creating-and-using-ios-prototype-cells-with-swift/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype cells are not showing without data source.

You can use `static cells` from the **content** type of tableView in the attributes inspector pan.